# Проблема с Update запросом Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Использую СУБД MYSQL.
Текст ошибки : You can't specify target table 'book' for update in FROM clause
Подскажите как нужно переписать запрос чтобы заработало

Мой запрос : `UPDATE book SET price = price * 0.95 WHERE amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM book)`

Answer (score 3):

В MySQL нельзя изменять таблицу, которая непосредственно участвует в фразе where. Необходимо использовать синтаксис update с join с подзапросом, который собственно получает значение:

```
UPDATE book n
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(amount) amount FROM book) b ON n.amount=b.amount
   SET price = price * 0.95
```

Если же вы точно уверены, что значение с максимальным amount в таблице только одно, можно применить более простой способ:

```
UPDATE book SET price = price * 0.95
 ORDER BY amount desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Akina Хм, согласен. Как то я об этом забыл ...